Tom Cat 10 / Java: The requested resource [/] is not available
Trying to run first project.Installed IntelijIDEA / Tom Cat 10 (tar.gz / zip). While running got this message
"The requested resource [/] is not available".
MacOS. Can someone help to solve this, been trying 2nd day. Watched so many videos which didn't help. Stuck in the beginning (...
Project Structure:
enter image description here
enter image description here
web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

Servlet.java
package kz.bitlab.servlets;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(value = "/home")
public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("<h1>First BITLAB Java EE Application</h1>");
    }
}


There may be nothing at /. What is the project called? What url are you calling? Try http://localhost:8080/<project name>/home to see if there is a response. Try http://localhost:8080/<project name>. Maybe add the TC startup logs to the question.

Fix the spelling of the name of the product, to promote searching.

Solved problem.
Turnder out that i need index.jsp file.
+updated web.xml:
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<display-name>Test</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>kz.bitlab.servlets.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


I assume u're trying to access HomeServlet.
You need defined your servlet in web.xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

If u're trying to create a welcome page, u should create an index.html (or index.jsp) under web package and modify welcome-file-list like this.
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


There is no need to declare a servlet in web.xml when it has the @WebServlet annotation
